# SockJS secure connection with IE8

Tags: spring, stomp, sockjs

Afternoon everyone. I'm having an issue with sockjs and Spring4. I don't know which side of the setup is causing the issue. The problem is I can't seem to get IE8 to open a connection to my Spring backend over HTTPS.

I'm trying to implament this example: https://demo.rasc.ch/spring4ws/ 
The link I'm trying is the chat. 
The link to his source is here: https://github.com/ralscha/spring4ws-demos

The only change I made to his source is I'm using jquery-1.9.1 , Spring 4.0.0, and the full stomp.js and not the stomp.min.js

The sock and stomp code in the index page for the chat client is:
        $(function() {
          var username, lastUsername, stompClient, content = $("#content")[0], 
          input = $("#editor input")[0];

```
      function notify(text) {
          $('<p class="message notice"/>').text(text).appendTo(content);
              content.scrollTop = content.scrollHeight;
      }

      $(input).keyup(function(event) {
          if (event.which === 13 && $.trim(input.value)) {
              if (!username) {
                 username = input.value;
                 $("#editor p").addClass("user").removeClass("guide").text(username);

                var path = window.location.pathname.substring(0,
                window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

                var sock = new SockJS(path + 'chat');
                stompClient = Stomp.over(sock);

                stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                     notify("The connection has been opened");
                     $(input).removeAttr("disabled").focus();

                     stompClient.subscribe("/queue/chatmessage", function(msg) {
                           var data = JSON.parse(msg.body);

                           if (lastUsername !== data.username) {
                              lastUsername = data.username;

                              $('<p class="user"/>').text(data.username).appendTo(content);
                }

                 $('<p class="message"/>').text(data.message).appendTo(content);
                 content.scrollTop = content.scrollHeight;

            });
        },
function(error) {
     notify("An error occured: " + error);
     $(input).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });
} else {
  stompClient.send("/queue/chatmessage", {}, JSON.stringify({username: username, message: input.value}));
}
 input.value = "";
}
});
$(input).focus();
$(window).resize(function() {
$(content).height($(window).height() - $("#editor").outerHeight(true) - 15).scrollTop(content.scrollHeight);
}).resize();
});
```

Sorry about the formatting.

In Spring all I did was separate the the webconfig java file into 2 files

WebConfig is standard. Extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter :

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html");
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
 configurer.enable();
```

}

WebSocket implaments WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer:

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
  registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS().setSessionCookieNeeded(false);
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
  registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/");
}

@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
  // use default thread pool with 1 thread
} 

@Override
public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
  registration.taskExecutor().corePoolSize(2).maxPoolSize(3);
}
```

The initilizer is basic too.

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
  return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class, WebSocketConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
  return new String[] { "/chatdemo/*" };
}
```

I'm also running this through Tomcat 7 using eclipse. So not the embedded tomcat.

The problem I'm having is the readystate inside sock is being set to permanent in IE. I don't fully understand xhr/xdr polling, but I'm assuming that's the problem.

Is there anything else I need to do to get IE to work over https on the sockjs side or the spring side?

Comment: Does any other browser work properly,  and the problem is only with ie8?